# URLCache don't save CacheURLResponse by request (using Alamofire)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsurlcache

I'm tying to save some response to URLCache:

```
var cache: URLCache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: 4 * 1024 * 1024, diskCapacity: 10 * 1024 * 1024, diskPath: nil)    
request.response { (dataResponse) in
            guard let response = dataResponse.response,
                let data = dataResponse.data,
                let request = request.request else { return }
            let cachedResponse = CachedURLResponse(response: response, data: data, userInfo: nil, storagePolicy: .allowed)
            print(cachedResponse)
            self.cache.storeCachedResponse(cachedResponse, for: request)
            print(self.cache.cachedResponse(for: request))
            
        }
```

But output is nil:

> NSCachedURLResponse: 0x6000000053e0
>
> nil

However size of cache used memory was increasing.

I've tried to create my own cache or using *URLCache.shared* instance

But response was always *nil*

Also I've tried to use another method of URLCache, that saves CachedResponse for task, and it save it only in case when task was in running state, but not in *suspended* state:

```
cache.storeCachedResponse(cachedResponse, for: task)
```

I'm really can't understand, whats happens inside this class.

P.S. I've read all article about URLCache, like these: http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/ https://blackpixel.com/writing/2012/05/caching-and-nsurlconnection.html

Comment: I assume, that methods of URLCache won't working with Alamofire request. But perfectly works with requests created directly by URLSession.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: Yes, don't use alamofire response. Use native NSURLSession Response

Comment: How do you get the 'native NSURLSession Response'? I tried creating new HTTPURLResponse(url: response.url!, statusCode: response.statusCode, httpVersion: "HTTP/1.1", headerFields: hackedHeaders), still not cached.

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but I assume it should be stored inside Alamofire wrapper response.